# Unable to use GPU processors for tensorflow LinearRegressor on Ubuntu (Titan-X pascal)

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, gpu

I have a (CUDA 8) - 3units of Titan-X Pascal on Ubuntu 16.04 with tensorflow v0.12. (Nvidia Driver Version: 370.28)

I have trouble running any contrib.learn modules (LinearRegressor) to use the processor (GPU-Util is always showing as 0% in nvidia-smi)

I know that my setup is correct because the cifar10 multi-gpu example (here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) works perfectly fine using all the GPUs.

I have also submitted an issue on tensorflow here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6132

Note: 
- I have changed the run_config to set allow_soft_placement=True
- I have tried adding specific GPU to model_fn as well as feed_fn separately but no luck.

Does anyone else face the same problem for contrib.learn packages? Any luck?